# Editor completely freezing

Tags: excel, vba, freeze

I was programming some buttons and comboboxes and so with Excel VBA. While trying these buttons it appears that the Excel VBE freezes completely. That means I don't get a "Excel is not responding" message, the window doesn't get grey. I just can't click anything in the VBE nor edit my code. Furthermore Excel doesn't run any of my code if I click one of my buttons.

Everything but the VBE still works fine. I can use the typical Excel formulas, make calculations and so on. This bug isn't really reproducible. It just kicks in after a certain combination of my three buttons.

Did anyone experience such a problem and know what could cause the Excel VBE not to respond at all?

Comment: Humour me by writing VBA.DoEvents in *any* loop in the code behind your button. If that resolves it then let me know.

Comment: Haven't experience such problem except when Excel is in edition mode (i.e. editing a cell formula/value) and try to go back to VBE and you can't do nothing! I guess that it is not enough? And what happen when you restart Excel?

Comment: can you step through your code and find out what line this error occurs?